# PHP code in HTML get commented out

Tags: php, html

When I put some PHP code in `example.html`, my PHP code does not show up in my browser (I use chrome).
In Chrome's dev tool the PHP tag

```
<?php include 'switch.php' ?>
```

becomes

```
<?-- include 'switch.php' -->
```

I want to know why this happens. That the PHP code gets commented out instead of getting processed.

I have Windows 7 with xampp.

Comment: You cannot include php code in `.html` files.

Comment: Can I in any other way embed or include php files in a html page?

Comment: why do you want it to be .html so bad? Just rename it to .php

Comment: the only other way I can think of is javascript or iframes, but, why?

Comment: You should include your code in a PHP file.

Comment: If I rename it to php do I need to add php tags outside the html tags?

Comment: No, only outside your php code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change page format from `.html` to `.php` . Then you can include php files !

Javascript and iframes are working too in php files IF they are not between `<?php ?>`